# Xamarin: Data Binding Converter for FFImageLoading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to `Xamarin` and try to use [this](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support) library to display `svg` graphics  in my `forms` app.
In the documentation it says, to use the `Data Binding`

> use a provided converter (eg. when using XAML):
>
> ```
> Source="{Binding SvgFileName, Converter={StaticResource SvgImageSourceConverter}}"
> ```

In the the documentation to `Data Binding` basics it says, that converters are for example to convert a `double` between 0 and 1 to an `int` between 0 to 255 for using it as a color.

But I don't understand, what this converter does though. Why cant I just use

```
Source="{Binding SvgFileName}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Converters` are a general aspect of `xamarin` and all `silverlight`/`wpf` alike technologies. They can be used to convert the the source of the binding into a different data format which then can be displayed in the `view`. You can find more information about them [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/), [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18849/how-do-i-use-ivalueconverters).

> I dont understand, what this converter does

It converts data from one type into a different type.

> Why cant I just use ...

You can use this; you just have to make source, that the member `SvgFileName` of the data context has a suitable data format ( e.g. `SvgImageSource`). If you want to use a file name (as your variable name suggests) you can use a converter to convert the file name to the `SvgImageSource` object.

All in all, this is most of the times not recommended, as it is much better to bind a data type like an `enum`, `bool`, etc. to the `view` and to load the real image source via a converter.